# Ember - Change current route from browser console

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I am not at all Ember developer, but I would like to change current route from browser console. Is it possible at all to access correctly Ember, e.g. `Ember.Router.prototype.transitionTo('/feed')`?

Version of the website is 3.16.9

Comment: you can utilize the `ember-inspector` to get access to the router service

Comment: Did you tried to fire a `popstate` event with your target route?

Comment: I was doing that for Linkedin and it seems that it's not listening to pushState/replaceState. I will post solutions that I've found

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I have found out possible solutions that you can use. I was trying to achieve it on Linkedin website via Chrome Extension

```
function runEmbedded(path) {
  const namespaces = window.Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES;
  let application;
  namespaces.forEach(function (namespace) {
    if (namespace instanceof window.Ember.Application) {
      application = namespace;
      return false;
    }
  });
  application.__container__.lookup('router:main').transitionTo(path);
}

const payload = '/some/new-path'
script.text = `(${runEmbedded.toString()})('${payload}');`;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

**Second solution/hack**:

Another possible hack to use, when the website is not listening to pushState/replaceState actions from History API is to push state 2 times and then go back. Please remember that's only a hack.

```
history.pushState({}, '', msg.payload);
history.pushState({}, '', msg.payload);
history.back();
```